# First android app last location returns null after sending coordinates through eclipse emulator control

Tags: android, android-emulator

All I am trying to do is a real simple app that gets the location that I send it via eclipse and displays it.  Location keeps returning null after lines below.

```
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Any help would be appreciated.  As of right now, i don't care about updating locations yet.

This is my first app, be gentle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this means that the GPS hasn't found a fix yet, since you're asking for a location immediately (It's actually returning null BEFORE you're sending co-ordinates through).

You need to make a Location Listener, which will listen for changes in the state of your GPS.

Here's an [example](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/).